# do action inside a class is not working

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, hooks, actions, post-type

I am trying to create my custom hook and call it from within a metabox class. Here is the pattern:

---

**metabox.php**

--

```
<?php
require("libs.php");
require("test.php");

class metabox() {
  function __construct() {
   add_action("add_meta_boxes", array($this, "mybox"));
  }

    function mybox($post_type) {    
     $post_types = array('post');       
      if (in_array( $post_type, $post_types)) {
       add_meta_box('box', __( 'Box Container', 'custom_box' ),
                    array( $this, 'baseBox' ), $post_type, 'normal', 'low');                
      } 
    }

function custom_box() {

callhook();

do_action("otherthing");
}

}

new metabox();
?>
```

---

**libs.php**

--

```
<?php
 function callhook() {
   do_action("something");
 }
?>
```

---

**test.php**

--

```
<?php
function test() {
echo "Test";
}
add_action("something", "test");

add_action("otherthing", "test");
?>
```

But it is output nothing, while is expected to output "Test" in the metabox!

What's the problem here and how to fix it?

Comment: where do you instance the class `metabox` ?

Comment: in the metabox.php file.

Comment: are you sure that your test.php is being loaded at all? You should use absolute paths when including a file.

Comment: yes, there is no error returned and I have checked all are corrects!

It works when I simply print a text inside the function located inside `libs.php`.

Comment: it doesn't seem like you call custom_box at all, therefor the action is not triggered.

Comment: I am sorry, my mistakes, I was hooking into the function's name instead of the hook's name in my file.